# JQuery make image invisible if outside div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a slider in JQuery. I have two images on top of eachother inside a div. When the right button is pressed I want to make the underlying image start left to it and slide it to the right on top of the other image. I use this code for that:

```
var position = $("#IMAGE1").position();
var width = position.left-1050;
$("#IMAGE1").css('left', width);
$("#IMAGE1").animate({"left": "+=1050px"}, "slow");
```

Now I only want the part of the image visible that is INSIDE the div, not when its outside (it would look really sloppy because the div has a border). Question is, how?

Comment: Just add the css style of `overflow: hidden;` to the containing div (be sure it has the proper width/height settings).

Comment: Show us a sample, then - link, jsFiddle, something.  And what does "doesn't work" mean, the image is bleeding out of the containing div? Do you have `position: relative` on the containing div?

Comment: the div container is div:absolute; and so are the images (I had to put the images on absolute because else the z-index doesn't work)

Comment: You need `overflow: hidden` as cale_b said on the *container div*

Comment: I put the container on overflow:hidden; as you said, but the images are still showing outside the borders of the div when I animate the images outside the div.

Comment: And the container **needs** to be relative.

Comment: Make an answer to the question so I can accept it, please :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure that the containing div has the following css styles:

```
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
```

That should do the trick.